# encodetime, incmilliseconds in delphi

Tags: delphi

i have create a coding to set a 20 millisecond faster than windows system. i'm using encodetime.

here's the code

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
delphi_datetime :tDateTime;
t_date : tdatetime ;
windows_datetime : tSystemTime;
begin
   t_date :=  dATE;
   delphi_datetime := encodetime(8,44,59,980);
   delphi_datetime := incmillisecond(delphi_datetime, 20);
   replacedate(t_date , delphi_datetime);
   datetimetosystemtime( delphi_datetime , windows_datetime );
   setlocaltime( windows_datetime );
  showmessage('time now = ' + timetostr(delphi_datetime));
end;
```

aftr i run it, show the correct time. but the date goes to 30 dec 1899.. but i want to the current today date but with the time faster 20 milliseconds. any help.. please...

Comment: What you mean by _set a 20 millisecond faster than windows system_?

Comment: @jachguate, I think OP wants here to change Windows system time by increasing 20ms.

Comment: @TLama - I think you are right, but I have little confidence that this can be done reliably.  A driver interrupt, especially if that generated a preemption, would quite possibly result in time going backwards.

Comment: AFAICS she is trying to set a fixed time (8:45), not to increase the current time by any amount.

Answer (score 6):

You have the arguments of `ReplaceDate` backward. It reads the date of the *second* parameter and assigns the date portion of the *first* parameter. The date portion of `delphi_datetime` is 0 because that's how `EncodeTime` works. You take that zero value and assign it to `t_date`, but then you continue working with `delphi_datetime`.

Reverse the arguments of `ReplaceDate`, and you should see that your current system time gets set to 8:45:00.000 with the current date.

```
ReplaceDate(delphi_datetime, t_date);
```

You could have noticed the mistake sooner if you hadn't used a separate `t_date` variable. If you'd called `Date` directly, your code would have failed to compile:

```
ReplaceDate(Date, delphi_datetime); // can't pass function result as "var" parameter
```

This works:

```
ReplaceDate(delphi_datetime, Date);
```

Comment: The fundamental problem here is that `ReplaceDate` and `ReplaceTime` are badly designed because they mutate existing values rather than returning new ones. Code like this is always easier to understand if we create new values each time. Languages with immutable types, or features like Java's `final`, allow the compiler to help. But with a language that doesn't, you can still choose to write code without mutating state.

Comment: I don't think that's the fundamental problem here, @David, since changing the procedure into a function would have no effect on the problem of getting the parameter order correct. The program would still compile and still yield an incorrect result if the statement had been written `delphi_datetime := ReplaceDate(t_date, delphi_datetime)`. We could argue that the fundamental problem was in opting to *use* `ReplaceDate` at all. I see no point in that function even existing since `DateOf` and `TimeOf` (or `Int` and `Frac`) make the operation trivial (and harder to mess up) anyway.

Comment: I don't mean change the procedure to a function. I mean use the alternatives in my answer, and your comment. The alternatives don't allow you to get the parameters wrong. ReplaceDate should be shunned.

Answer (score 4):

Rob has identified problems with your existing code. However your existing approach is needlessly complex. If you chose a simpler approach you would find it easier to get the code right.

If you want a date time that is 20 milliseconds greater than now, do it like this:

```
MyDateTime := IncMillisecond(Now, 20);
```

If you want a date time representing 0845 today, then you write:

```
MyDateTime := Date + EncodeTime(8, 45, 0, 0);
```

Comment: hi david heffernan and rob kennedy.. thank you verry much for your help:)